# Removing a certain user from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've looked on the internet but I can't get my head round to it using `Array.splice`.

I store data to my map the following way:

```
    usersPlaying.push({
        user: user.id,
        current: point
    });
```

Then when they are done playing the game I want to remove them from the array using, most likely, `Array.splice`. How can I remove, or splice, the value that has a certain `user.id` as user, so I know which user to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.findIndex()` to find the index of the element of the array that you are trying to match where return value from the function call is passed as first parameter to `.splice()` with second parameter set to `1`

```js
let usersPlaying = [];

let user = {
  id: 123
};

let point = 0;

usersPlaying.push({
  user: user.id,
  current: point
});

console.log(usersPlaying);

usersPlaying.splice(
  usersPlaying.findIndex(({user, current}) => 
    user === user.id && current === point
  )
, 1);

console.log(usersPlaying);
```

Comment: Okay, so I could run it like ` usersPlaying.findIndex(({user, current}) => 
    user == 32
  )`

Then it would remove the user with the id 32 from the list, where is the `1` for if I may ask?

Comment: @MartijnEbbens Yes. `1` is [`deleteCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) parameter _"An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove. "_

Comment: What if I wanted to edit the data? Let's say I wanted to edit the user his point, how would I do that? Also, why does usersPlaying.findIndex(({user, current}) => user == 32 ) return `-1` should't it return `0` / `1`?

Comment: @MartijnEbbens Editing the element is a different question from removing the element from the array. You can use `.find()` to find the element. Where is `32` defined? Can you include the array that you are using at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried the following, usersPlaying.find(user => user === 1). This returns undefined.

Comment: `({user, current})` at parameter of function destructures the object element of the array to set `user` as the identifier for `user` property and `current` as identifier for `current` property, without using `obj.user`, or `obj.current`. `usersPlaying.find(user => user === 1)` is different from `usersPlaying.find(({user}) => user === 1)`

Comment: It now says Unexpected Token at { }, so I guess I'm doing something wrong again. lol

Comment: I dug a little deeper into finding the data and I figured it out, thanks for the help on the question(s) above though!

Comment: If destructuring assignment is used at a function parameter the parameter should be enclosed in `()`, within `()` `{property}`, that is `({property})` is a reference to for example `var obj = {property:123}`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var users = [{user:1, current:10}, {user:2, current:8}, {user:3, current:12}];

function removeUserById( userId) {
    return users.filter(function(u) {
        return u.user != userId;
    })
};

console.log( removeUserById(2));

//ES6

var removeUserByIdES6 = userId => users.filter( u => u.user != userId); 
console.log( removeUserByIdES6(2));

// This will remove the user from the original array

var removeUser = userId => users.find( (u,i) => u.user == userId && users.splice(i,1)); 
removeUser(2);
console.log( users);
```

This will remove a user with a certain id without affecting the original array.

Comment: `.filter()` returns a new array. OP is trying to remove an element from an existing array.

Comment: Yes, I've added destructive version with `splice` that will remove the element from the original array

Comment: Are you not still creating a new array with `.map()` call?

Comment: Yes, I've changed it to `find`